# How to get an array of elements and click a random one with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer and given a list of topics with the same tag structure I need to click a random one.
If I use document.querySelector and click a random topic it works but I am not sure I can use page.evaluate because later on I need to repeat the click again and make sure the previous topic.

The error I am getting is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: page.$(...).click is not a function
```

Upon debugging topics array gives me an ElementHandle array and the randomNumber is -1.

My code is this:

```
  await page.waitForSelector('.o-topicselect__list');
  // get the all li elements
  const topics = await page.$$('.o-topicselect__list li')
  // create a random number from 0 to the topics.length-1
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * topics.length - 1);
  // click a random topic
  await page.$(`.o-topicselect__list li:nth-child(${randomNumber}) a`).click()
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Andrea, what is exactly are looking to solve? Randomnumber being -1 or not being able to click?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * topics.length);` — you need not `- 1` here as the length is already more than the last array index.

Comment: @Vaviloff I am sorry I wasn't clear. I am trying to get the element clicked, but I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to run `.click()` on a promise.  You need to first wait for the promise returned by `page.$` to resolve to an `ElementHandle`, and then you can click it:

```
let link = await page.$(`.o-topicselect__list li:nth-child(${randomNumber}) a`);
await link.click();
```